# Redirect admin user based on role

Tags: admin, adminhtml, redirect, user-roles

We have several admin roles for our product and based on that role they could be redirected to a different section for their initial page. That being said I was curious how to redirect an admin user after authentication to a specific page based on their admin role?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can configure the startup page on a global scope (`System > Configuration > Admin Startup Page`), there is no core functionality to redirect different roles to different places. If you wanted to add such functionality, then rewriting `Mage_Admin_Model_User::getStartupPageUrl()` would probably be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` by following code

```
  <admin>
        <routers>
            <admin_modulename>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Modulename</module>
                    <frontName>admin_modulename</frontName>
                </args>
            </admin_modulename>
             <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Modulename before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_Admin</Namespace_Modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
  </admin>
```

create `IndexController.php` in following path

**app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Adminhtml/Admin/IndexController.php**

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_Admin_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    { 
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
        $url = $session->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl();
        if ($session->isFirstPageAfterLogin()) {
            // retain the "first page after login" value in session (before redirect)
            $session->setIsFirstPageAfterLogin(true);
        }
/* custom code start */

    $configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');

        if($configValue == 'supplier') // supllier is role name
            $url= 'WRITE HERE YOUR URL WHERE YOU WANT TO REDIRECT';
       else if($configValue == 'employee') // employee is role name
            $url= 'WRITE HERE YOUR URL WHERE YOU WANT TO REDIRECT';

/* custom code end */
        $this->_redirect($url);
    }

}
```

If you want to more about `Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');` then refer this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892476/how-to-get-data-from-magento-system-configuration